# SDK lost track of where I defined my AVDs

Tags: android, emulation

I installed the latest SDK, but around the same time I also installed a separate instance of a different version of the SDK in a different location (I don't know what version it is).  I don't know whether the latter fact is relevant.

For my convenience, I defined a ANDROID_SDK_HOME env var that points to where I installed the SDK.  I added the tools and platform-tools from that into my PATH.

At some point I ran the SDK manager and installed or updated several packages, including platform-tools (I obviously did this before the previous step).

I ran the AVD manager and created an AVD for ICS.  I ran the AVD a couple of times and ran some simple tests.

That was yesterday.  Today when I tried to run the emulator using that AVD, it said:

> PANIC: Could not open: "path to android sdk".android/avd/"my avd
>   name".ini

This is curious, because my ".android" directory where my AVD is defined is in my Windows HOME.

I then ran the AVD manager, and not surprisingly, it said that I don't have any AVDs in "path to android sdk".android/avd, instead of referring to ".android/avd" in my Windows HOME.

I'm not sure what happened here.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just create a new AVD? One thing you could do (no guarantees on this) is copy all of your files from your original AVD to another location.. make a new AVD.. copy your old files over this new AVD.. cross your fingers and hope :P otherwise I'd say just create a new AVD (unless you had critical stuff on the original)

Comment: Sure, I could create a new one, but who's to say tomorrow it will get confused again and think my AVDs are in my HOME/.android?  I need to understand why it lost track of where they were, so I can either fix it or just know how to move forward.

Comment: Try deleting `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` and rebooting.

Comment: Just to be clear, I assume you mean to remove the environment variable, not the directory it points to? Are you suggesting this because you believe the "ANDROID_SDK_HOME" environment variable is "special" somehow?  Even if it is, it seems to be pretty clear what it should point to, and that's what I have it pointing to.

Comment: I note that at http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html#DefaultLocation it clearly says that %HOME%\.android is where it expects this to be, but this implies that you could change it, but not how you would change it.  I tried running "regedit" and searching for "android", but I never saw anything that appeared to refer to this directory.

Comment: Ok, I get it now.  ANDROID_SDK_HOME is supposed to point where your ".android" directory is, and it uses %HOME% by default.  This is different from what I usually expect for "framework_HOME" variables, but this works.  @CommonsWare: if you post that statement as an answer, I'll mark it as the correct answer (although a little more elaboration on the answer would be appreciated for other other people who might have this issue in the future).

Comment: The reason I didn't make it an answer or provide elaboration was that it was somewhere between "educated guess" and "random shot in the dark"... :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and had to set the full path to the AVD home, as in `D:\Android\sdk\.android\avd`. The error reads as though just setting the sdk directory or windows home directory is sufficient, but until I set my AVD home to include the `.android\avd` path I had a similar error.

An example where I'm storing AVD's outside of my windows home dir:

```
ANDROID_AVD_HOME=D:\Android\sdk\.android\avd
ANDROID_SDK_HOME=D:\Android\sdk
```

Answer (score 0):

`ANDROID_SDK_HOME` can be used, at least on Windows, as an environment variable pointing at where your SDK *data* will reside. This is ill-documented, at best.

Hence, having it point to your SDK *installation* will cause confusion, as soon as the `adb` daemon process picks up on the environment variable change (e.g., reboot).

Either don't have `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` (to pick up the default location of your `.android` directory) or make sure it points to where Android can find your `.android` directory.